Angular 16 ViewChild components in NgbOffcanvas is returning undefined
I have an offcanvas and a x-component in it and whenever I try to use ViewChild to get the x-component, it always returns undefined.
Error
(https://i.sstatic.net/Lh6DUTZd.png)
Code
import { Component, inject, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { LazyloadedComponent } from '../lazyloaded/lazyloaded.component';
import { NgbOffcanvas } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-offcanvas',
  templateUrl: './offcanvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./offcanvas.component.scss']
})
export class OffcanvasComponent {

  @ViewChild('offcanvas') offcanvas: TemplateRef<OffcanvasComponent>;
  @ViewChild('lazy') lazy: LazyloadedComponent;
  private offcanvasService = inject(NgbOffcanvas);
  
  open() {
    this.offcanvasService.open(this.offcanvas);
  }

  test() {
    this.lazy.test();
  }
}

<ng-template #offcanvas let-offcanvas>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <app-lazyloaded #lazy></app-lazyloaded>
        <button (click)="test()">TEST</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>

When I replicate the issue on Angular 18, it doesn't happen anymore.
Repo for reference: https://github.com/jim-dev12/angular-16-ngb-viewchild-issue
Stackblitz for reference: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/jim-dev12/angular-16-ngb-viewchild-issue
Tried using @ViewChild to access the component properties. I expected it to access the property normally but it is returning undefined.

When you take a plain ViewChild using template reference variables (#lazy) it will usually give you the ElementRef (HTML element reference inside nativeElement property) of the element.
@ViewChild('lazy') lazy: LazyloadedComponent;

But in this scenario, you require the actual component. Here are two ways to solve the issue:

You can use the second argument of ViewChild which is an object with a property called read, this can be used to specify what dependency injection token you require from the template reference variable.
 @ViewChild('lazy', { read: LazyloadedComponent }) lazy: LazyloadedComponent;


Another alternative is to specify the DI token directly on the ViewChild, which will be nothing but the component itself. Here we can remove the template reference variable #lazy from the HTML
 @ViewChild(LazyloadedComponent ) lazy: LazyloadedComponent;



Full Code:
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { OffcanvasComponent } from './offcanvas/offcanvas.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(OffcanvasComponent) offcanvas: OffcanvasComponent; // <- changed here!

  openOffcanvas() {
    this.offcanvas.open();
  }
}

Working Github Fork

@JimGarrido updated with working github repo
